# How to get data from database between two string time?

Tags: php, mysql

Right now I'm facing the issue for related to get the data from database.
The issue is that in the database time field is a string and I need to get data between to times so I'm not able to get that data

**Database**

```
r_value varchar(250)

r_date date

r_time varchar(10)
```

**Query**

```
SELECT SUM(r_value) as reading FROM [TABLE NAME] WHERE d_id in (7596)
    AND DATE_FORMAT(r_date, "%Y-%m-%d") = "2017-06-28" 
    AND r_time >= "12:00 AM" AND r_time <= "07:12 am"
```

So please help me how to get data between thous two string time?

Comment: you should use datetime  .. instead  of a date and a varchar ..

Answer (score 0):

For both date and time you would better use timestamp.

Timestamp is server independent.

I suggest you change the field type to `timestamp` and then easily search against it. For example:

```
SELECT SUM(r_value) as reading FROM [TABLE NAME] WHERE d_id in (7596)
    AND r_date = '1498631600'
    AND r_time >= '1498631600' AND r_time <= '1498631600'
```

Or So

```
SELECT SUM(r_value) as reading FROM [TABLE NAME] WHERE d_id in (7596)
    AND r_date = unix_timestamp('2017-01-01')
    AND r_time >= unix_timestamp('2017-01-01 00:00:00') AND r_time <= unix_timestamp('2017-01-01 00:00:00')
```

Also you can show your date and time in any format you want in your client.